# How to fix a wrong PHP path on mac?

Tags: php, macos, path

I tried to change my default PHP path to MAMP PHP path but I typed in the wrong path without stating the version folder in MAMP.

I used:

```
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin:$PATH"
```

instead of:

```
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.10/bin:$PATH"
```

as a result commands like `which php` and even `vim` doesn't work. How can I change the path now if `vim ~/.bash_profile` command can't be found?

Comment: I'm not sure, but can't you just enter: `export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.10/bin:$PATH"` in the terminal and then open vim and change back? However, you still export $PATH so vim should still work, no?

Comment: I think you have overwritten your existing path entries with the MAMP one which is why it can't find those commands

Comment: vim is just a program on your computer, you should still be able to type in the full path to the vim executable and run it. I don't know where it exists, but I would just assume one of the obvious paths like `/usr/bin`

Comment: I've located the `.bash_profile` file manually and changed it, but other commands still don't work